# can't figure out the issue with counter in sqlite

Tags: python, database, sqlite, discord.py

So what this does is, if I add a word to the db, it's supposed to +1 to the count for the respective word every time it's typed

I can add the word to the db, but the counting system isn't working

```
@commands.command()
    async def wordadd(self, ctx, *args: str):
        message = " ".join(args).lower()
        word = db.column("SELECT word FROM words")
        if message not in word:
            db.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO words (word) VALUES (?)",message)
            db.commit()
            await ctx.send("word has been added")
        else:
            await ctx.send("word already in there")


    async def on_message(self, message):
        word = db.column("SELECT word FROM words")

        if message in word:
            db.execute("UPDATE words SET count = count + 1 WHERE word = ?", message)
            db.commit()
```

how can I fix the counting system?

Comment: `message = " ".join(args).lower()` is probably not doing what you want it to. You can test this with `print(" ".join("test").lower())`, which will print `t e s t`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
import discord
import sqlite3

from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

async def get_messages():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM messages")
    return c.fetchall()

async def add_message(message):
    with conn:
        c.execute("UPDATE message SET messages=:message",
            {'messages': message})

async def remove_message(message):
    with conn:
        c.execute("DELETE message=:message FROM message",
            {'message': message})

async def add_user_message(user_id, message):
    with conn:
        c.execute("UPDATE message SET messages=:message + messages WHERE user_id=:user_id",
            {'message': message, 'user_id': user_id})

@client.command()
async def add_message(ctx, *, message: str):
    check = get_messages()
    if check:
        await ctx.send("That word is already on the database!")
        return
    else:
        msg = message.lower()
        await add_message(msg)
        await ctx.send("Succesfully added {}".format(message))
        return

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    check = await get_messages()
    if message.content.lower() in check:
        await add_user_message(message.author.id, 1)
    else:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.run("token")
```